# ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist in Oracle 9

Tags: oracle

I'm getting this error when I try and connect to database in Oracle 9 (running on Windows 2003 server)

I've tried to manually start the Oracle service but it refuses to start....

Answer (score 1):

try that: On the server, log in as an administrator, then:

```
SQLPLUS /nog
connect / as sysdba
startup
```

any error messages?

Comment: I got this errors. "ORA-00838: Specified value of MEMORY_TARGET is too small, needs to be at least 3256M
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters"

Comment: @Pumayk26 look here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=ora-00838-specified-value-of-memory-target-is-too-small

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried to manually start the
>   Oracle service but it refuses to
>   start....

So, somewhere there is an error message related to this.  Check the Windows event log, both System and Application.  Also check the Oracle alert log, which is probably in %ORACLE_HOME%\admin\*sid*;  There may also be trace files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've got this on *nix, its been due to to the ORACLE_HOME being set not quite right. Can't really help with Windows though.

Answer (score 0):

look in the sqlnet.ora file and make sure that its set as:
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(NONE) and not (NTS)

Go to Control Panel, Services, select the OracleService, right click 
and select properties, select the Log On tab. Click on the Account radio button 
and make sure the account being used is a domain qualified dba user and the password supplied is correct.  Hit apply and okay and try to start the service.

If it still fails look in the alert log for that sid and see what the error is.  Make sure also that no changes have been made to the spfile use by the database to start the instance.  If so move the corrupt spfile out of the way and create a pfile to start the database with.

Answer (score 0):

My experience from a Unix environment:

I hit the same problem even though it seemed both ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME were configured properly for the first glance.

In my case, the problem was in the ORACLE_HOME as it is expected not to end with a slash char. When I removed the ending slash from the value, things started to work fine.

```
# WRONG, leading to ORA-27101:
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/oracle/11gR2/

# CORRECTLY set up:
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/oracle/11gR2
```

So, my suggestion is, even if it looks fine, check the ORACLE_HOME variable for the trailing slash.